# Is it possible to set scrolloff to top and bottom with different values?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

As title. For example, say I imagine there is something like `scrolloffTop` and `scrolloffBottom` and I can set each with different values. If there is no such options, I would like to know is it possible to achieve this by script.

Comment: There are no such options, AFAIK; `scrolloff` is what there is.

Comment: So sad. I need these option...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a script that will set a different `scrolloff` value when the cursor is in the top or bottom half of the window (**12** and **0** respectively in the example).

It uses the `CursorMoved` event, which will trigger quite often. This might not be the best approach.

```
augroup switchScrolloffTopBottom
  autocmd!
  autocmd CursorMoved * if winline() < &lines/2
        \| setlocal scrolloff=12
        \|else
        \| setlocal scrolloff=0 
        \|endif
augroup END
```

Comment: I'm willing to burn my CPU to have this feature. Thanks a lot!